# Problem to set a subquerie on bigquery no matching operator and unrecognize table in the subquerie

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to run the below querie on bigquerie and I am getting an error related to not matching at the inner join clause.

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  name,
  number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      start_station_id,
      COUNT(*) number_of_rides
    FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
    GROUP BY
      start_station_id
  )
  AS station_num_trips
  INNER JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` ON station_id = start_station_id
  ORDER BY
    number_of_rides DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its the inner join that the problem, My first observation is your `SELECT` statement looks odd where are you getting `station_id` and `name` from? I suspect if you just run the first part of your query you will not find any data in the `station_id` and this is why it will not join with the other file